# Receiving data from Wikipedia API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I’m trying to get data back from the wikipedia api. Please help me understand why, in the first two lines of code, I do succeed in receiving the data, while afterwards, when I use JQuery's `onclick`, I do not.
I shortened and simplified the code for your convenience, just take into notice that the `onclick` works fine.
For further investigation please check the full code on https://codepen.io/Yonatanos/pen/RZadQL

```js
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=test&callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data); // In this case i can see the data
  });

  $("#send").on("click", function() {
    var query = $("#search").val();
    console.log(query);
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + encodeURI(query) + "&callback=?";
    console.log(url); //Receiving successful output
    console.log('test');
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      console.log("Testing it"); //No ouput
      console.log("data"); //No output
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="_blank"><button id="randomSearch">Click here for a random Wiki Article</button></a>
<form action="#" method="get">
  <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Insert Search Term" autocomplete="off">
  <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: if you add a `console.log('test')` juste before the `getJSON` does it show something in your console?

Comment: Is `#send` a dynamically created element? _"I shortened and simplified the code for your convenience"_ Convenience is not necessary. The code that you are actually using would be more helpful to resolving issue than lack thereof. Can you include HTML at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is `#send` a form button and page is reloading?

Comment: Note there were two syntax errors at HTML `id-"randomSearch"` should be `id="randomSearch"` and `<input>` element is self-closing. Prevent the default action of `<form>` submission

Comment: Is this right `console.log("data"); //No output` ? Or this is typo?
I think this is typo, data is variable `console.log(data); //No output` remove double quotes

Comment: Thank you all!
Apperantly the problem appeared on my Microsoft Edge browser. When changed to Google Chrome all the data appeared.